# php + mySQL authorization stack

Tags: php, mysql, authorization

Can somebody point me why validation of user-login from my database returns me only `1`.

Every time function returns me `1` why does that happend?!

Here is my `PHP` code

```
if (isset($_POST['auth'])) {
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

// определяем начальные данные
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'blog2';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_table_to_show = 'posts';
// соединяемся с сервером базы данных
$connect_to_db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name)
    or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

# проверяем, не сущестует ли пользователя с таким именем
$query = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE login='admin'");
echo mysqli_num_rows($query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {
    echo 'true';
}  else {
    echo 'false';
}`
```

And here is my DB structure.

- [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auDTk.png)
- [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mei0f.png)

Comment: Fixed code and grammer

Answer (score 0):

Because you used COUNT() function which will count the rows that have the login name is admin

Comment: if you want to select id of the user that have login name =admin then

Comment: "SELECT id  FROM users WHERE login='admin'"

Comment: it will return the id of the user you are searching for

Comment: Thanks! My fault, thas question  was rly lamer)